# How to filter based on two conditions in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want sno where level is 5836 alone, if the sno has multiple levels even if it has 5836, it must be ignored.

| sno | levels |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5836 |
| 1 | 5838 |
| 2 | 5838 |
| 2 | 5836 |
| 3 | 5836 |
| 4 | 5838 |
| 5 | 5836 |

Expected Output

| sno | levels |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5836 |
| 5 | 5836 |

This is what I tried, but I think logic isnt working

```
with T1 as
(
SELECT id, levels
from tablename
)
select id
from T1
where levels = 5836 and levels <> 5838
```

[dbfiddle] (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9cc0b0e8a42fb181754ccca7a40d774b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select sno
from tablename
group by sno
having min(level) = 5836 and min(level) = max(level);
```